# Adding two ruby arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to find a way to add two arrays together. For instance is there a way to add 
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [4,5,6]
to get the result
    c = [5,7,9]

Comment: What happens when one array has more elements than the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is when the arrays aren't the same sizes:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [4,5,6]
ary = a.map.with_index{ |m,i| m + b[i].to_i }
=> [5, 7]

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
ary = a.map.with_index{ |m,i| m + b[i].to_i }
=> [5, 7, 3]
```

If the second array is shorter it works. If the first array is shorter it truncates the length of the resulting array to fit. That might not be what you want.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
ary = a.map.with_index{ |m,i| m + b[i].to_i }
=> [5, 7, 9]
```

Fixing the problem with the array-lengths changes things a little. I'd do this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
ary = a.zip(b).each_with_object([]){ |( a,b ), m| m << a + b.to_i }
=> [5, 7, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't have better than this : `c = a.zip(b).map { |x, y| x + y }`

Assuming your arrays have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for same length arrays:

```
[a,b].transpose.map{|x| x.reduce :+}
```

Especially useful when adding multiple arrays:

```
[a,b,c,d,e].transpose.map{|x| x.reduce :+}
```