# Adding two arrays in Ruby when the array length will always be the same

Tags: ruby, arrays

So, I need to add two arrays together to populate a third. EG

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,5,6]
```

so that:

```
c = [4,6,8,10]
```

I read the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584585/adding-two-ruby-arrays

but I'm using the codecademy labs ruby editor and it's not working there, plus the lengths of my arrays are ALWAYS going to be equal. Also, I don't have any idea what the method ".with_index" is or does and I don't understand why it's necessary to use ".to_i" when the value is already an integer.

It seems like this should be really simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,5,6]
a.zip(b).map { |i,j| i+j } # => [4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Here

```
a.zip(b) # => [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
```

and `map` converts each 2-tuple to the sum of its elements.

Comment: What does the zip method do?

Comment: Nathan_U, I anticipated your question :-)  Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! So, zip puts both values together to make a 2d array, and map changes the values to the sum with { |i,j| i+j }. What I'm trying to do is create a one-time pad program as I'm learning ruby. So my question was to enable me to XOR the message by the key. All I need to do now is learn how to turn the characters into binary and back again and I'll be 70% there!

Comment: Nathan_U, have a look at [Fixnum#to_s(base)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) and [String#to_i(base)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1**:

For a *pure Ruby* solution, try the [`transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,5,6]
c = [a, b].transpose.map{|x, y| x + y} 
#=> [4,6,8,10]
```

**OPTION 2**:

If you're in a Rails environment, you can utilize Rails' [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
[a, b].transpose.map{|x| x.sum} 
#=> [4,6,8,10]
```

**EXPLANATION**:

`transpose` works perfectly for your scenario, since it raises an `IndexError` if the sub-arrays don't have the same length. From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

> Assumes that self is an array of arrays and transposes the rows and columns.
>   If the length of the subarrays don’t match, an IndexError is raised.

Comment: What exactly does the transpose method do?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation of both the Ruby `transpose` method and the Rails `sum` method.